# onclick function retrieving and filtering xml not working

Tags: ajax

I need to select some options (three multiple-choice menu) and than to call a function, by clicking on a button, to retrieve a xml file, to filter the results (according to the options selected) and to display them. It is a very simple task, but I am new at coding. I can retrieve and filter the xml file when I load the page, but if I associate the loading and filtering function to an onclick event, then it does not work. I have to clue how to solve it, but I think it should be very easy for a coder. Here the external javascript code:

```
function filtra(){

    var sito = $('#sito option:selected').val();
    var epoca = $('#epoca option:selected').val();
    var tipo = $('#tipo option:selected').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'data.xml',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: xmlParser

            });
        };



        function xmlParser(xml) {
            $(xml).find('reperto').each(function(){

                    if (($(this).find("sito").attr('id') == sito || $(this).find("sito").text() == sito) && ($(this).find("epoca").attr('id') == epoca || $(this).find("epoca").text() == epoca) && ($(this).find("tipo").attr('id') == tipo || $(this).find("tipo").text() == tipo)) {

                    $('#container').append('<div align="left"><img src="reperti/' + $(this).find("foto").text() + '" width="200" height="225"></div>');
                    $('#container').append('<div><p>' + $(this).find("testo").text() + '</p></div>');
                        };

            });

        };
```

enter code here

Comment: How **"it does not work"**?

Comment: Meaning that nothing happens, and I do not understand why. If I retrieve and filter my xml file when the page is loaded, using $(document).ready, then it perfectly works: I can display the data I want to be displayed. If I call the same function to retrieve the xml with an onclick event, then nothing happens. I still have no idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables `sito`, `epoca` and `tipo` in function `filtra()` and your variables in your function `xmlParser()` aren't in the same scope.

Your  variables `sito`, `epoca` and `tipo` in `xmlParser()` have, instead of having the values you selected in your dropdown menu, are your dropdown menus.
That's because they have the same id as the name of the variable.

To fix this you need to put them in the same scope.

You can either put your AJAX handler `xmlParser()` inside your `filtra()` function

```
function filtra() {
    var sito = $('#sito option:selected').val();
    var epoca = $('#epoca option:selected').val();
    var tipo = $('#tipo option:selected').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'data.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('reperto').each(function() {
                if (($(this).find("sito").attr('id') == sito || $(this).find("sito").text() == sito) && ($(this).find("epoca").attr('id') == epoca || $(this).find("epoca").text() == epoca) && ($(this).find("tipo").attr('id') == tipo || $(this).find("tipo").text() == tipo)) {
                    $('#container').append('<div align="left"><img src="reperti/' + $(this).find("foto").text() + '" width="200" height="225"></div>');
                    $('#container').append('<div><p>' + $(this).find("testo").text() + '</p></div>');
                };
            });
        }
    });
};
```

or move your assignment of your variables into the `xmlParser()` function

```
function filtra() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'data.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: xmlParser
    });
};

function xmlParser(xml) {
    var sito = $('#sito option:selected').val();
    var epoca = $('#epoca option:selected').val();
    var tipo = $('#tipo option:selected').val();

    $(xml).find('reperto').each(function() {
        if (($(this).find("sito").attr('id') == sito || $(this).find("sito").text() == sito) && ($(this).find("epoca").attr('id') == epoca || $(this).find("epoca").text() == epoca) && ($(this).find("tipo").attr('id') == tipo || $(this).find("tipo").text() == tipo)) {
            $('#container').append('<div align="left"><img src="reperti/' + $(this).find("foto").text() + '" width="200" height="225"></div>');
            $('#container').append('<div><p>' + $(this).find("testo").text() + '</p></div>');
        };
    });
};
```

To debug your code you should use `console.log(variable);` to check what is actually executed and if your variables have the value they are supposed to.

You can view that output in your web-dev console. You can open it with <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: thank you very much, you saved my day (and also thanks for the suggestion on how to debug my code). now the problem is to clean the results and perform another search (with new variables) every time I click on the function filtra()... Thanks again!

Comment: @GeorgWoyzeck If my answer helped you, you should accept it.